# How to perform a signed PUT request with OAuth in Python

Tags: python, oauth

How is this meant to work? Where are all the oauth_* values meant to go if not in an encoded body like a POST request? In what form do you sign it?

All the Python OAuth libraries I can find only support GET and POST. Does anyone know any that support all methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[python-oauth2](http://github.com/simplegeo/python-oauth2/issues#issue/5) supports all HTTP verbs -- as the comment I've linked to says, and I quote,

> We use PUT extensively at SimpleGeo
>   (our python-simplegeo package uses
>   python-oauth2 and PUT requests).
>
> The python-oauth2 package's client
>   (oauth2.Client) simply wraps httplib2,
>   which supports all of the verbs AFAIK.

So were did you get the weird notion that python-oauth2 doesn't support PUT?